# JDialog in front its JFrame parent

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I want to create in Java Swing a JDialog which, when it's open, its parent window cannot be accessed (just like when you open the file explorer dialog in Microsoft Word). Is there any method in the JDialog class that provides this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

use JDialog.setModal(true) before setting dialog visible

```
JDialog yourdialog = ...

yourdialog.setModal(true);
...

yourdialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: or use one of the JDialog constructors that defines the modality.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

Use the static methods in `JOptionPane`.  These will create modal dialogs by default:

```
Window parentWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parentPanel);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parentWindow, "Hello, World); // Create modal dialog aligned with parent window.
```

Create a `JDialog` explicitly:

```
Window parentWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(parentPanel);
JDialog dlg = new JDialog(parentWindow, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

The first option is far simpler and I tend to prefer it particularly with modal dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Adamski and Jan both have the correct answers already, but I wanted to just make sure that the concept of a modal window is explained.

The OP asked about a dialog that blocks access to the parent. This is called a modal dialog (or a modal window). Wikipedia gives [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window):

> In user interface design, a modal window is a child window that requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application

So, "modal" means that it will block parent windows (users cannot interact with any window besides the modal window), while "non-modal", or "modeless" means that the child and parent windows will be accessible at the same time.

This is a concept that exists in GUI frameworks in general, not just the Swing framework. In any GUI framework that you use, you can probably find this kind of functionality by looking for a `modal` property.

Answer (score 0):

how about to lock JDialog inside his JFrame Parent ?
it's true that using JDialog.setModal capable to making jdialog just like dialog on other application. stopped all frame bofore jDialog closed

Comment: It seems that you have an answer that is a bit different from the others, but it isn't very clear. I don't really understand what you mean by "locking" a JDialog inside its parent. Could you explain your idea a little more?